# Java Prepared Statement Parameters in SELECT Clause

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

is it possible to set parameters in the SELECT clause in a prepared statement in Java? Something like this:

```
PreparedStatement prepStat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT ? 'Typ' FROM employee");

    prepStat.setString(1, typ);
    ResultSet rs = prepStat.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next())
    {
        String strFilter = rs.getString("Typ");
        System.out.println("strFilter: "+strFilter);
    }
```

When I execute those lines, I only get the header of the column and not the values. When I execute the query without the question mark in SQL Server, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Bind variables can only be used to bind **values**, not syntactic constructs or object names. The value you are binding is interpreted as a string literal, and since a literal only has one value, applying `distinct` to it will return a single line.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The problem is that with "normal" statements the application is really slow. Do you have a suggestion to make it faster?